# How to read the cassandra nodetool histograms percentile and other columns?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, nodetool, nosql

How to read the cassandra nodetool histograms percentile and other coulmns?

```
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)                  
50%             1.00             14.24           4055.27               149                 2
75%            35.00             17.08          17436.92               149                 2
95%            35.00             24.60          74975.55               642                 2
98%            86.00             35.43         129557.75               770                 2
99%           103.00             51.01         186563.16               770                 2
Min             0.00              2.76             51.01               104                 2
Max           124.00       36904729.27       12359319.16               924                 2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They show the distribution of the metrics. For example, in your data the write latency for 95% of the requests were 24.60 microseconds or less. 95% of the partitions are 642 bytes or less with 2 cells. The SStables column is how many sstables are touched on a read, so 95% or read requests are looking at 35 sstables (this is fairly high).

Comment: Thank you! Does it make sense to say 99% of read requests have touched 103 SStables and 95% of read requests have touched 35 SStables?

Comment: yeah, with a -c option (in some 2.0 versions, later versions remove it) you can see the actual histogram values. You probably have had just a few requests that are really bad, touching over 100 sstables.

Comment: when I say  99% of read requests have touched 103 how is that very few? I think I missing a major point.

Comment: thats not very few, thats a lot. 103 is bad. but since its only at 99th percentile it means that youve had very few requests that have taken that many

Comment: I see. so is it appropriate to say 1% of read requests have touched 103 SStables?

Comment: Kind of, you can say the worst 1% touched 103 or more sstables. The bottom 99% touched 103 or less.

You know the max is 124 sstables so theres between 103 and 124 sstables for the worst 1% of queries.

Comment: This percentile thing is not very intuitive because you seem to be ok with saying "worst 1% touched 103 or more sstables" and "99% of read requests have touched 103" while they both sound contradictory

Comment: "99% of read requests have touched 103 or less". check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile which may describe it better. "A percentile (or a centile) is a measure used in statistics indicating the value below which a given percentage of observations in a group of observations fall."

Comment: Lets say I assume that is true but 99% of read requests are not very few! But you second comment says "You probably have had just a few requests that are really bad, touching over 100 sstables". That is what I dont seem to understand