# Read and Write Performance calculation in apache cassandra

Tags: cassandra, benchmarking, cassandra-3.0

I would like to track and calculate the READ and WRITE performance in Apache Cassandra (Client - cqlsh). I know TRACING ON is available, but I didn't find that much useful.

I expect to track the following examples in Cassandra (Examples),

```
I have 3 node Cassandra cluster and I have a table with 1 million entry, I would like to calculate the performance of READ / WRITE in the following way,

1) WRITE - 1 INSERT with 1 million entry available in it.
2) WRITE - 1 UPSERT on one of the entry with 1 million entry available in it.
3) READ - 1 READ from 1 million entry 
4) READ - ALL THE 1 million entry

which involves single partition and multiple partition too.
```

Any help for tracking performance is appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statistics about performance for particular keyspace/table could be obtained via `nodetool tablehistograms` command (as described [in documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsTablehisto.html)).

For generation of load against tables you can use `cassandra-stress` tool that comes together with Cassandra.  It quite powerful, but requires writing of correct configuration file that mimics your tables.  This [blog post](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2017/02/08/Modeling-real-life-workloads-with-cassandra-stress.html) is quite helpful together with [official documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCStress.html).

Comment: what does the next two comment mean? Doc doesn't have much information neither this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688069/how-to-read-the-cassandra-nodetool-histograms-percentile-and-other-columns

Comment: table historgram headings : Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count

Comment: Its value : 99%             1.00            263.21            263.21              2299               310

Comment: The first value - this is percentile - this means that 99% of transactions have this number. 2nd - number of SSTable files, 3rd - max write latency for this percentile is 264 microseconds, 4th - read latency (strange that you have both of them with same value), 5th - size of single partition in bytes, and last one - number of cells (individual values) inside this partition - because you have time as clustering key, partition includes multiple "rows"

Comment: Does this mean, 3rd - max write latency for this percentile is 264 microseconds - 99% of my request took max of 264 micro seconds? same for 4th also? If possible could you please clarify the 3rd and 4th points more clearly

Comment: Also I have 800 entries in that table, How come cell count is 310?

Comment: To give you info, SSTable Dump : "cells" : [
          { "name" : "flashmode", "value" : "yes" },
          { "name" : "physicalusage", "value" : 38 },
          { "name" : "readbw", "value" : 29 },
          { "name" : "readiops", "value" : 12 },
          { "name" : "totalcapacity", "value" : 20 },
          { "name" : "writebw", "value" : 28 },
          { "name" : "writeiops", "value" : 81 },
          { "name" : "writelatency", "value" : 4 }
        ]

Comment: 310 - number of cells in individual partition(s) - some partitions may have more data, some a less. Regarding latency - yes, that's correct - the max time for 99% of your read or write requests are ~264 microseconds.  But I believe that this data isn't very representative of the real performance

Comment: Another piece of cake for your brother : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793714/how-partition-read-is-choosen-in-cassandra

Comment: I am so curious, How the data inside a single partition is distributed, So Could you guide me in this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793714/how-partition-read-is-choosen-in-cassandra