# How partition read is chosen in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have 3 nodes with number of partition data distributed across 3 nodes,

When I look for the end points with partition key like below,

```
./nodetool getendpoints keyspacename tablename partitionkeyvalue
172.30.56.63
172.30.56.62
172.30.56.61
```

I am also able to see from the `./nodetool ring` that the different partitions are distributed from -2 power 63 to +2 power 63 using virtual nodes

I am also able to see the queried hosts (using the response object) that It used the token aware policy to choose the co-ordinator node

Let's say the partition contains 1 billion entries with RF = 3.  Will the data inside a single partition be distributed across nodes? Or a single cassandra node will have the complete partition data and the other two nodes will have the complete replica of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The individual partition always resides on single node, with replicas on other nodes. That's why there are recommendations on the max size of partition: ~100Mb in 2.0 & below, or several hundred MBs in higher versions.  The number of cells inside partition will depend on the average size of the values, etc. - in DS220 Data Modelling course there is a separate set of lectures on physical model.

Comment: Awesome, Life saver :), So what happens If the size on the single partition grows above several hundred Mbs? I understand the size of the data in Harddisk will increase, but how cassandra reacts?

Comment: One more question, Always the read for the data will happen from the partition set in the nodetool ring right?

Comment: For 1st - performance will be not very optimal as it will need to process/transfer more data.  For 2nd - I did not completely understand the question, but yes, data will be distributed in give ring range.

Comment: My question is let;s say the partition key in the ring lies for Node 1, then does it mean the data for that partition key will always be read from Node 1

Comment: This node is responsible for primary replica, but data could be read from other nodes as well. This may depend on selected consistency level

Comment: If the replication factor is 3 with Read Consistency as 1 
And ./nodetool ring says the partition key (Example : 222567180698744628) is alloated for the 172.30.56.61 like below,

Comment: 172.30.56.61  rack1       Up     Normal  338.87 KiB      74.73%              221601083445796573

Comment: Does it mean that, Always the 172.30.56.61 will perform the READ for that partition until the node is going down?

Comment: No, coordinator node that handles request will select "fastest" replica based on information received via gossip - there are multiple factors that affects performance of node, such as performing of major compaction, or something like. In this case, sending an additional request to that node will put additional load to it, that isn't desirable

Comment: Using result set, I am able to find the CO-ORDINATOR node using the response result set : ResultSet {
  info: 
   { queriedHost: '172.30.56.61:9042',
     triedHosts: { '172.30.56.61:9042': null },
     speculativeExecutions: 0,
     achievedConsistency: 10,
     traceId: undefined,
     warnings: undefined,
     customPayload: undefined } but how to see from which node the read happens ?

Comment: I mean how to identify the node selected by coordinator node for read ?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is correct way, but you may try to enable tracing of your requests - in this case, ResultsSet can return tracequery object that you can use for for lookups in `system_traces`

Comment: I am curious on this because If the coordinator is going to decide which node to choose for read based on the replicated data why do we need to have this mapping in the nodetool ring '
 
172.30.56.61 rack1 Up Normal 338.87 KiB 74.73% 221601083445796573 '

Comment: As per my understanding, '221601083445796573' will be served by 172.30.56.61 (until it goes down) Since it is currently mapped in the nodetool ring for 172.30.56.61. But your statement above contradict with this, so why do we need this mapping to the partition, if coordinator is going to choose it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161208/discussion-between-alex-ott-and-harry).